# problems with matlab wavrecord and wavread

Tags: matlab, voice-recognition

I have a problem in matlab

I want to record a speech for 2 seconds then read the recorded sound and plot it

I use the code

```
FS = 8000;    
new_wav = wavrecord(2*FS,FS,'int16');
x = wavread(new_wav);
plot(x);
```

but the error appears

```
??? Error using ==> fileparts at 20
Input must be a row vector of characters.

Error in ==> wavread>open_wav at 193
[pat,nam,ext] = fileparts(file);

Error in ==> wavread at 65
[fid,msg] = open_wav(file);

Error in ==> test at 2
x = wavread(new_wav);
```

I plotted correctly recorded sound files, but when I want to record new one through matlab I get this errors.

I tried many ways by changing FS and 'int16' but nothing happens.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [WAVRECORD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/wavrecord.html) doesn't write data to a file, it only returns a data vector for `new_wav`, so this variable is what you should be plotting. The function [WAVREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/wavread.html) reads data *from a file*, so it expects a character string as the input. That's the source of the error you're getting.

If you want to save the data from [WAVRECORD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/wavrecord.html) to a file, you need to use the function [WAVWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/wavwrite.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input('Enter Your Name   ','s');
file = sprintf('%s%s.wav','train - ',name);
input ('You have 2 seconds to a word. Press enter when ready ')
y = wavrecord (2*fs,fs);
wavwrite(y,fs,file);
```

Comment: Code has still errors when I tried it...Error using wavwrite>OpenWaveWrite (line 169) Unable to open file. Reason: Permission denied Error in wavwrite (line 95)
fid = OpenWaveWrite(wavefile);

Answer (score 0):

At the end this is the complete code :)

% Record your voice for 5 seconds.

```
recObj = audiorecorder;
disp('Start speaking.')
recordblocking(recObj, 3);
disp('End of Recording.');
```

% Play back the recording.

```
play(recObj);
```

% Store data in double-precision array.

```
myRecording = getaudiodata(recObj);
```

% Plot the waveform.

```
plot(myRecording);
```